# Quadratic formula solver in python

Tags: python, math, compiler-errors

I'm somewhat new to python, but I'm trying my best to learn. My code is

```
import math

a = 5
b = 5
c = 5

def quad_solve(a, b, c):
    q1 = b*b
    q2 = 4*a*c
    q3 = 2*a
    q4 = q1-q2
    sqr = math.sqrt(q4)
    sol1p1 = b+sqr
    sol1p2 = sol1p1/2
    sol2p1 = b-sqr
    sol2p2 = sol2p1/2
    print ("(",sol1p2,",",sol2p2,")")

quad_solve(a, b, c)
```

And when I run it it gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 19, in <module>
  File "python", line 12, in quad_solve
ValueError: math domain error
```

which I don't really understand.

I'm trying to create a quadratic formula solver. I use the math module, and then define three variables, a, b, and c. Then, I define a function that takes in those variables (I call the function at the end). In the function, I define four quantities. `q1` is the b squared under the square root, `q2` is the 4ac also under the square root, `q3` is the denominator, and `q4` calculates the total under the square root (i.e., `q1` - `q2`). Then, I define a variable called `sqr` which is equal to the square root of `q4`. Then, I define four more variables, which calculate the solutions. `sol1p1` takes b + sqr, and `sol1p2` takes `sol1p1` and divides it by two. This gives the first solution. Then, `sol2p1` takes b - sqr, and `sol2p2` takes `sol2p1` and divides it by two. Finally, `sol1p2` and `sol2p2` are printed, in a set of parentheses with a comma between. I hope that makes sense; if any clarification is needed about the variable names, please let me know.

I am using the online compiler repl.it (I don't know if there's anything special to consider with that).

Thanks!

---

**Edit:**

I updated my code, per Code Apprentice's recommendations. I started by adding an if statement:

```
import math

a = 5
b = 5
c = 5

def quad_solve(a, b, c):
    q1 = b*b
    q2 = 4*a*c
    q3 = 2*a
    q4 = q1-q2
    check = math.tan(q2)
    if (q1 > check):
        sqr = math.sqrt(q4)
        sol1p1 = b+sqr
        sol1p2 = sol1p1/2
        sol2p1 = b-sqr
        sol2p2 = sol2p1/2
        print ("(",sol1p2,",",sol2p2,")")
    else:
        print "Imaginary number. There are no zeros."

    quad_solve(a, b, c)
```

but it is continuing to return the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 23, in <module>
  File "python", line 14, in quad_solve
ValueError: math domain error
```

I'm not sure why.

Comment: Which line is line 12?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, line 12 is `sqr = math.sqrt(q4)`, line 19 is `quad_solve(a, b, c)`.

Comment: The algorithm is mathematically correct. However, you have failed to take into account the case where `q4` is negative. In math, what do you get when you take the square root of a negative number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my version of the answer in the fewest lines of code:

```
import cmath

#Your Variables
a = 5
b = 5
c = 5

#The Discriminant
d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)

#The Solutions
solution1 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
solution2 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
print (solution1)
print (solution2)
```

Comment: Because it uses complex numbers.  Do you know what those are?  It would help a great deal if you'd do the hand calculation for the constants you input to know what the answer should be before you begin.  You should be taking care of special cases (e.g. a = 0, b = 0, c = 0).

Answer (score 1):

b^2 has to be greater than 4ac, So right now, that `sqrt()` function is getting a negative number.

Comment: @heather What is the square root of -25, for example?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, well, an imaginary number. Wait, so then I need to test if b^2 > tan 4ac, and if it isn't, return that there are no zeros? Then, I guess I'd want to know if I can have it handle imaginary numbers.

Comment: @heather Right, the `sqrt()` function in Python does not deal with imaginary numbers. It will just throw an error if you try to take the square root of a negative.

Comment: @heather So either you have to detect this case and avoid it, or you have to change your code to use imaginary numbers.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, ah! Okay, then how do you take care of imaginary numbers?

Comment: @heather I should say `math.sqrt()` doesn't do imaginary numbers. As Tom Pitts shows in his answer, you can use `cmath.sqrt()` instead.

Comment: @PabloIocco The OP clearly understands all of the mathematics involved here. She just didn't know about the nuances of Python and `math.sqrt()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yes, thank you. I do understand the mathematics. Good to know about `math.sqrt()`. I'll be updating my question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @heather As you continue to learn to program, you will find that correct mathematical reasoning will sometimes encounter the limitations of computers in ways similar to this. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in getting a result (and not in learning how to do this), you can use [sympy](http://sympy.org):

```
from sympy import var, solve

x = var("x")
print(solve(5*x**2 + 5*x + 5))
# prints [-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2, -1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2]
```

Comment: Thank you, but actually, I can calculate the result just fine, plus there's stuff like Wolfram Alpha. That's a good thing to know, but for now I'd like to learn how to do it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this (I figured this out thanks to the great hints given by Code-Apprentice, Pablo Iocco, and Tom Pitts).

```
import cmath
import math

a = 1
b = 3
c = 2

def quad_solve_exact(a, b, c):
    d = (b*b)-(4*a*c)
    solution1 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    solution2 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    print (solution1,solution2)

quad_solve_exact(a, b, c)

def quad_solve(a, b, c):
    if (b*b > 4*a*c):
        print "There is a solution!"
        d = math.sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c))
        solution1 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
        solution2 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
        print (solution1,solution2)
    else:
        print "No solutions, imaginary number"

quad_solve(a, b, c)
```

The first way is the more exact. The problem is the `sqrt` function used by the normal `math` package can't handle negative numbers. There is a package, `cmath`, however, that *can* handle negative numbers. So, you import both packages (the normal `math` package is used in the second example) and then define a, b, and c. Then, in your function you can combine the variables much more than I did, leading to shorter/clearer code. So, the variable `d` is used to denote what is under the square root. Then, for each solution, -b is added or subtracted to the square root of `d`, all of which is divided by 2a. Then, the solutions are printed.

The second solution is less exact, but perfectly serviceable for my purposes. The new function also takes a, b, and c. Then, an if statement is used to make sure that the number being square rooted is not negative. If it is negative, then the else statement is ran, which prints that there is no solution. If the variables pass the if statement, it prints that there is indeed a solution, and basically uses the same code as before, except instead of `cmath.sqrt`, `math.sqrt` is used.

Comment: Note that there's a single real solution when the discriminant (b² - 4ac) equals zero. Technically, we say that there's a double root in that situation. Graphically, the graph of the function just touches the X-axis at the double root.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import cmath
a=float(input("Enter a: "))
b=float(input("Enter b: "))
c=float(input("Enter c: "))
sol 1=(-b-cmath.sqrt(b**2)-(4*a*c)/(2*a))
sol 2=(-b+cmath.sqrt(b**2)-(4*a*c)/(2*a))
print("x = {0}and{1}".format (sol1,sol2))
```

Please give me a feedback on if it worked out

Answer (score 0):

This is my initial try for a quadratic solver while trying to learn python.
It's very basic and doesn't check for imaginary solutions.
It will just fail if the solution is not real.

```
# Second order quadratic solver: ax^2 + bx + c


import math

def testinput(userinput):
    try:
        val = float(userinput)
    except ValueError:
        print("\n\n\nENTER REAL NUMBERS \n\n\n")

print("ax^2 + bx + c quadratic solver")



a = input("Enter a:")
testinput(a)
a = float(a)

b = input("Enter b:")
testinput(b)
b = float(b)

c = input("Enter c:")
testinput(c)
c = float(c)

x1 = (-b+math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a)
x2 = (-b-math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a)

print("\n\nInput: %.2fx^2 + %.2fx + %.2f\n" %(a,b,c))
print("\nSolution: x1 = %.3f , x2 = %.3f\n\n" %(x1,x2))
```